# Azure App Gateway SSL Offloading to a Datacentre server?

Tags: azure, ssl, offloading

So I am looking at using Azure App Gateway to overcome a set of legacy servers (Win2003) that will not support TLS 1.2 and therefore come March+ 2020 the client browsers will not be able to access the site.

So my question is can I use AZ App Gateway to terminate the SSL and route traffic onto a set of Windows Load Balanced servers in our datacentres?

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this, but Azure Front Door would be a better option, I believe (if you trust IP restrictions, I think that would be the only way to secure endpoints). They  would allow you to offload SSL and offer some other nice features. And you don't have to create site-to-site vpn and maintain it.